# Long Polling SQS Messages From Lambda Function With Batch Size = 1 and Reserved Concurrency = 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, concurrency, microservices, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda function with SQS Event Trigger. Here is the list of parameters I have for this lambda and the connected SQS queue:

Lambda:

- Reserved Concurrency = 1
- Batch Size = 1
- Batch Windows = none
- Retry Attempts = 2
- Time out = 1 min 15 sec

SQS:

- Visibility Timeout = 8 mins
- Message Retention Period = 4 days
- Delivery Delay = 0 sec
- Receive Message Wait Time = 20 sec
- Maximum Receives = 5

The main SQS queue is also connected to a Dead Letter Queue.

The problem that I have is that almost 20-30% of messages in the queue NEVER end up processed by the lambda. So at the end, I am losing them.

For some reason, I have to limit concurrency = 1 and batch size = 1. So changing those two parameters is not an option for me.

Any recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us your code that processes the events. Specifically, are you looping through the **multiple `Records`** that are passed to the function? Many people hard-code to `Record[0]` and miss the other records that are passed-in.

Comment: Batch Size is 1, so I am not having multiple records, at the moment of processing messages.

Comment: The reason you need to limit it to Batch Size 1 is probably because your code is not processing all records being sent to the function. Please Edit your question to show the part of your code that loops through the event records.

Comment: The reason I need to limit it to Batch Size 1 is because I want it to be like that. I already explained this in question. The other thing is that I can confirm that I am receiving messages with batch size 1. So I am not losing any messages in my lambda code. My problem is that with current configuration, some messages never reach to lambda.

Comment: Just to check... Is your function calling `ReceiveMessages()`, or is it using the records passed through the `event` parameter?

Comment: I am processing event.msg. And for the record, I have some cloudwatch logs before this. This means if I detect a message in lambda, I first send a log to cloudwatch. For missing jobs, there is no logs in cloudwatch. That is the reason I am telling some jobs even not triggered by lambda.

Comment: Please Edit your question to show us the `for` loop that you use to process the `event` records.